# I have two lists. One of variable names one of initial values. I need to combine them so they can be used in function evaluation

Tags: python

I have three lists imported from a.csv file variable names, initial values, and constraints.

```
variables = [x1,x2,x3]
```

and a list of initial values

```
intialvalues = [1,2,5]
```

and a third list of constraints

```
constraints = ['x1+x2', 'x2-x3']
```

I am looking for a way to break the lists into variables so that the constraints can be evaluated using `eval()`.

EDIT: Example .csv file

```
Varible Names,Initial Values,Constraints
x1,1,x1+x2
x2,2,x2-x1
x3,3,x3+x2
,,x1+x3
```

The column names are obviously discarded while reading.

Comment: `x1 = initalvalues[0]`. That first list seems unncessary

Comment: Anyways, seems like you might need [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#a-more-interesting-example)

Comment: I need the fist list cause the program can't define the variable names they are all defined in the .csv file provided at run time.

Comment: Edited it with an example don't know if it's what your are looking for

Comment: Alright, so how are these "constraints" working? Like `x1+x2 = 1 + 2 = 3`... How is that a constraint?

Comment: Basically they each get evaluated to check if they are greater than zero..the problem is none of these are know until run time.  The variable names could be anything the initial values could be any number and the constraints could be any algerbraic expression of any combination of variables

Comment: You might want to use those 'variable names' not as variable names, but as some other sort of reference.  Eg, dictionary keys.  Then you can substitute keys/values into strings to your hearts content (and eval the string without using variables at all).  Not sure if this would meet your requirements.  In general, if you're trying to create variables with names from an external source, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok so looks like a dictionary is the way to go for variables. Is there an easy way to parse the constraints for the dictionary keys or am I going to need to parse them all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can declare your variables within the namespace, but modifying `globals()` and using `eval()` is really a terrible thing to do, so take this only as an example.

```
variables = ['x1','x2','x3']
intialvalues = [1,2,5]
for var, val in zip(variables, intialvalues):
    globals()[var] = val

constraints = ['x1+x2', 'x2-x3'] 
for c in map(eval, constraints):
    print(c)

# 3
# -3
```